# Exact notation of the domain of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, notation

> For example, we have $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-1}$

Would the domain be $$\mathcal D(f)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x\neq(1,-1)\}$$ or rather
$$\mathcal D(f)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x\neq \{1,-1\}\}$$ or $$ D(f)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x \setminus \{1,-1\}\}$$ or are all notations correct?

Comment: $\{ x \in \mathbb R \mid x \ne 1 \text { and } x \ne -1 \}$.

Comment: The first one is wrong because $(1,-1)$ in set theory usually is an ordered pair. In analysis $(a,b)$ usually denotes an *interval*.

Comment: Second is wrong because $\{ 1, -1 \}$ is a set; thus, we may have $x \notin \{ 1, -1 \}$.

Comment: Thir one is wrong because "$\setminus$" is an operation between sets, and $x$ is not a set.

Comment: None is really correct. With a slight abuse of notations, you can write $\;\mathcal D(f)=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid x\ne 1,-1\}$ or just $\;\mathcal D(f)=\Bbb R\smallsetminus\{ 1,-1\}$.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.

Comment: I'd say they are all wrong but the first two I'd know what is meant.  (I wouldn't even notice 2) is wrong unless I looked.  3 in my opinion is weird and unclear but I imagine others may intuitively accept it as I intuitively would accept 2) even though it is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Hint:** The flaws in OP's proposals have already been identified in the comment section. Note, it is often convenient to write
>
> $$\mathcal D(f)=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1,1\}$$

Answer (score 1):

> For example, we have $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-1}$

The domain $\mathcal D$ would be *(suggested from Mauro ALLEGRANZA)*:

$$\mathcal{D}(f)=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x\neq 1 \wedge x\neq -1\right\}$$